# How to animate progress bar that looks same as in win 7 or win 8.1 style?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created an application which will consist of a progress bar and a button.When I click the button it will do some operations in the background and gradually the progress bar gets incremented.
Now the issue is when I run the application in windows 7,The progress bar is animated like exactly in windows 7 and 8.1, but when I run the same application in win 10 it's not at all displaying animations it is just simply progressing without any animations.

How to animate the progress bar so that it exactly behave same way in all windows platforms(consist animations while progress)?[application behavior in  Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDM8B.jpg)   and [behavior in win 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFqP7.jpg).

Comment: ProgressBar uses the visual styles renderer that matches the operating system.  Win10 has a new look-and-feel, it is "flat" to match what's considered in vogue today in design.  How controls like that automagically adopt the design style of the OS is normally considered a feature and not a bug, it keeps your own design current for years to come so it doesn't look like the gaudy VB6 forms do today.  And of course it isn't going to surprise your user, he will be quite familiar with how the progress bar is *supposed* to look from other apps.  Don't fix it.

Comment: Hi Hans,thank you for the quick response. I understand that it is not a bug, but i want to customize the progress bar style so that it can get animated(like windows 7) in all windows flavors.

Comment: Code to draw and animate ProgressBar [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/297061/17034).  You'll however have to use DrawThemeBackgroundEx() in C++.  Keep in mind that you have to animate yourself, use a timer.  You'll get the legacy Win7 visual style even on Win10.  Hopefully enough to convince you to not do this :)